# Como apagar arquivo ou pasta em Linguagem C

Tags: c

Como excluir um arquivo ou pasta pelo código em linguagem  c,  já tentei usar o método `remove(pt);` mas não funcionou,  tentei usar comandos do dos e não funcionou também.

Comment: O comando básico é este, se não funcionou tem algo errado no seu código. Poste ele e indique o que tem de errado para podermos ajudar.

Comment: poste o seu codigo, ira facilitar a localizao do seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

No Linux precisa usar a funcao `remove`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    remove("caminho completo do arquivo ex. /home/user/arquivo.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Consulte o manual da funcao [`remove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html).

*OBS: Em C chamamos isso de funcao, nao metodo.*

Comment: Essa é a forma canônica em C, seja no Linux ou em qualquer sistema operacional.

Answer (score 0):

A função se chama `remove()`, declarada em `<stdio.h>`. Leia sobre ela na sua referência favorita (como você parece usar Windows, provavelmente será a MSDN).

Para deletar um arquivo, usamos a função `remove("nome_do_arquivo")`. No exemplo abaixo o programa deletará o arquivo `stack.txt`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    remove("stack.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Depois de analisar a situação toda, deixei conforme o edit aprovado pelo @Higor, até com algumas melhorias. O unico problema é que agora a resposta ficou igual as outras duas postadas antes da correção

Answer (score 0):

exemplo basico com um simples teste para saber se foi deletado ou nao.

```
int retorno;
   char arquivo[] = "arquivo.txt";

   retorno = remove(arquivo);

   if(retorno == 0) {
      printf("deletado");
   } else {
      printf("nao deletado");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de como apagar arquivo e pasta no windows usando *Windows.h*.

```
void deletar_arquivo (string caminho) {

    DeleteFileA(caminho.c_str());
}

void deletar_pasta (string pasta) {

    RemoveDirectoryA(pasta.c_str());
}
```